# ISC DHCPD multiple subnets but want only one subnet to do ddns updates to a windows server dns

Tags: dhcpd

I have a Ubuntu server providing dhcpd services to multiple subnets without any problems.  One of the subnets has a Windows 2008 AD.  We want to have the ISC DHCPD server on the Ubuntu server to provide dhcp and update the windows 2008 AD DNS.  The ddns configurations are global and that makes the dhcp server send ddns update for the other subnets to the Windows 2008 AD DNS.  Would like to only do ddns update to the Windows AD only on the one subnet the Windows server is on.   I've tried groups and putting some of the ddns commands in the subnet directives but none of this worked.  Do I need to run a different instance of isc-dhcp-server to provide this ddns update on just the subnet that needs it?????

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.  Global option ddns-domainname  locks all dhcp requests to that domain name and forwards all to the dns server.  Removing the ddns-domainname global option and using only the 'option domain-name' within the subnet will have the dhcp server forward only ddns updates to the 'option domain-name' dns server defined in the 'zone' definition.